# Check if an item is always followed by another in a list - Python

Tags: python, regex, list

I would like to check if one item is always followed with another within a list. I have come up with this really trite example... Let's say I would like to check if "a" is always followed by "b" in the following list:

```
list = ['x','y','z','a','b','2','3','5','2','1','5','fds','f','s','a','b']
```

Then, ideally, the function would return TRUE if every time we see an "a", it is directly followed by a "b". Can anyone help me with this? Maybe I am missing something really simple here.

Comment: `list` is not the best name as it collides with `list` builtin type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
all(a != 'a' or b == 'b' for a, b in zip(list[:-1], list[1:]))
```

Comment: Wow, that was amazingly quick. Thanks very much! I can get back to work now, haha :)

Comment: @AshishAcharya then you need to use `not any(...)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `all` with `zip` for an O(n) solution.

`itertools.islice` is used to avoid the expensive of making a new list. You can also wrap in a function as below.

```
from itertools import islice

def fun(lst, val1, val2):
    return all(j==val2 for i, j in zip(lst, islice(lst, 1, None)) if i==val1)

lst = ['x','y','z','a','b','2','3','5','2','1','5','fds','f','s','a','b']

res = fun(lst, 'a', 'b')

print(res)  # True
```